# Equivalent of Access Crosstab Query in SAS?

Tags: sas

Here is my Input:

```
ID  Color
1   green
1   red
1   orange
1   green
1   red
2   red
2   red
2   blue
3   green
3   red
```

Here is what I want in my output - a count of records by ID for each color:

```
ID  green  red  orange blue
1   2      2    1      0
2   0      2    0      1
3   1      1    0      0
```

I know I can get the information using proc freq, but I want to output a dataset exactly like the one I have written above.  I can't seem to figure out how to make the colors the columns in this output dataset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first, generate the data.

```
data data;
    format ID 8. Color $8.;
    input id color;
datalines;
1   green
1   red
1   orange
1   green
1   red
2   red
2   red
2   blue
3   green
3   red
run;
```

next, summarize color counts by id.

```
proc freq data=data noprint;
    table id*color / out=freq;
run;
```

make the table flat.

```
proc transpose data=freq out=freq_trans(drop=_:);
    id color;
    by id;
    var count;
run;
```

optionally, fill in missing cells with 0.

```
data freq_trans_filled;
    set freq_trans;
    array c(*) green red orange blue;
    do i = 1 to dim(c);
        if c[i]=. then c[i]=0;
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fill the missing cells with zero's using the `SPARSE` option to the `PROC FREQ`'s `TABLE` statement. This way, you don't need another `DATA` step. The order of the colors can also be controlled by the `ORDER=` option to `PROC FREQ`.

```
data one;
  input id color :$8.;
datalines;
1   green
1   red
1   orange
1   green
1   red
2   red
2   red
2   blue
3   green
3   red
run;
proc freq data=one noprint order=data;
  table id*color /out=freq sparse;
run;
proc transpose data=freq out=two(drop=_:);
    id color;
    by id;
    var count;
run;
proc print data=two noobs;
run;
/* on lst
id    green    red    orange    blue
 1      2       2        1        0
 2      0       2        0        1
 3      1       1        0        0
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never been a fan of proc transpose because I can never remember the syntax.  Here's a way to do it with proc sql and a macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;  
    select    sum(color = '" || trim(color) || "') as " || color into: color_list separated by ", "
    from      (select distinct color from one);  
    create table result as  
    select    id,  
              &color_list  
    from      one  
    group by  id;  
quit;



id            blue        green         orange            red  
1              0              2              1              2  
2              1              0              0              2  
3              0              1              0              1
```

Comment: This code has mis-matched quotations. Can someone correct them so I can understand this technique?

Comment: It is just missing the opening double quote. Here is the code generation using CATX() to make the pieces a little easier to see. `select catx(' ','sum(COLOR=',quote(trim(COLOR)),') as',COLOR)` so you end up with code like `sum(COLOR="blue") as blue`

Answer (score 0):

For (pteranodon), I happened to be reviewing the archives(6+ yrs later) which is why so untimely, but someone may benefit.

```
    proc sql noprint feedback;  
     select    catx(' ','sum(color =',quote(trim(color)),') as',color) into: color_list separated by ", "
       from (select distinct color from one);  
     create table result as  
      select id, &color_list  
      from one 
      group by id;  
    quit;
```